# flip or change camera during call webrtc

Tags: xamarin.forms, webrtc, peerjs

i have mobile app which is developed in xamarin form. I am running webview on that for video call, now everything is working fine only i  am not able to switch front or back camera during running video call.

Here is what i have tried so far but didnt succeed.

i have added select option in html code where i can choose front or back camera and here is the code of javascript

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
 
    var valueSelected = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
    alert(valueSelected);
    //var myselect = 0;

    if (valueSelected == "0") {
        var cameras = [];
        devices.forEach(function (device) {
            'videoinput' === device.kind && cameras.push(device.deviceId);
        });
        var constraints = { video: { deviceId: { exact: cameras[0] } } };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {            // Set your video displays
            window.localStream = stream;
            myapp.setMyVideo(window.localStream)
            if (callback)
                callback();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
            alert('Unable to call ' + err.name)
        });
    }
    else {
        var cameras = [];
        devices.forEach(function (device) {
            'videoinput' === device.kind && cameras.push(device.deviceId);
        });
        var constraints = { video: { deviceId: { exact: cameras[1] } } };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {            // Set your video displays
            window.localStream = stream;
            myapp.setMyVideo(window.localStream)
            if (callback)
                callback();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
            alert('Unable to call ' + err.name)
        });
    }
    //var myselect = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
   
    });
});
```

when video call start by defaul it open back camera